# Any ways / alternatives for AdSense approval for a website that is not based on rich text content

Tags: google, google-adsense, content, advertising

Hello I have following website -> http://musicglaze.com and have applied for AdSense, but was quickly rejected due to "insufficient content" As you can see nature of the website is not to provide much written content, as opposed to audio. Therefore I can not add more text in it than just headings with song authors and names. I'm looking for ways to get approved for google adsense, is there anything I can do? Or will I have to consider another ad publishing platform? If so what other platforms are good? However I don't understand how sites like http://9gag.com have Adsense on them, when there is no content besides images? I understand those are extremely popular, yet how come they can get approved for adsense and my website can't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Google says they want "sufficient content" for Adsense they mean two things:

1. You need enough text on each page so that they can tell what the page is about.  That means that each page needs at minimum

   - A title that uses appropriate keywords
   - A sentence or two describing the content
2. Enough original content or commentary hosted on your site

   - They don't accept sites that only have embedded YouTube videos.  They require unique commentary about the videos.
   - They don't accept sites that only post content taken from other sites.  It has to be unique to the site serving adsense.

Comment: So Say if I add paragraph for each song, describing it, lats say 3 - 5 lines of text, will that be sufficient enough?